# Difference between Mainform batch and XML batch in command line

Tags: c#, xml, args

I am new to C# and I dont get the following lines of code. The second part where the main form is loading(inside the else condition), is familiar to me. But the first part where the code reads from args[0] is a bit tough for me to understand. Can anyone help pls? i need to understand clearly what's happening here. Any links would be fine too. I have no idea how to begin searching

```
if (args.Length > 0 && ("xml" == args[0].Substring(args[0].Length - 3)))     
               {
                  BatchApplicationContext context = new BatchApplicationContext(args[0]);
                  if (context.ReturnValue == 0) Application.Run(context);
                  ret = context.ReturnValue;
               }
               else
               {
                  Properties.Brand.InitializeHook("App.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                  MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(args);
                  if (mainForm != null && !mainForm.DoExit) Application.Run(mainForm);   
               }
```

Comment: Argument are the command line you would type from cmd.exe window that are the parameters of main (string[] args).  In this case item zero is the executable file name.  I think the code should be using args[1].

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you suggest me some link to read about this in detail. It would be helpful.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: thanks :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it checks for the existence of "xml" in the beginning of the command line arguments passed to the application
and
either

(1) instantiates the BatchApplicationContext class passing the argument to the constructor of such
    (I do not know of such a class that is part of the .Net Framework, is this a user defined class?)
    Application.Run(context) Specifies the contextual information about an application thread, so my
    guess is that they are using a custom class (user defined) to create the  context object for use
    in this code block

OR

(2) instantiates the MainForm passing the argument to the constructor of such and then displays the form if successfully loaded